# Was "wasn't Chaplin in that one?" an expression in the 1920s?

Tags: expressions, cliche, twentieth-century-english

*Boardwalk Empire* has Nucky saying to his showgirl ("Billy Kent" a smart person who made little jokes often) girlfriend as he describes helping feed his impoverished family as a child when she asks something like, "And were you able to eat?" and he replies, "I only stole enough for 3."

She then says "Wasn't Chaplin in that one?" and indeed, his reply sounds like the sort of title of a silent film.

EDIT:

My question is "Wasn't Chaplin in that one?" a phrase/cliche that people would use when the other person said something that was flowery or unusual?

Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Can you express this in the form of a question, one that indicates what kind of answer you want? It sounds like you could be asking several different things, some of which are much too opinion-based to work here.

Comment: @StuartF: I am asking the question in the title. The body explains background.

Comment: What is the question? The title contains two '?' marks, the second of which doesn't form a question. The first paragraph has "Nucky saying to his girlfriend" but omits what he said. The middle paragraph is vague: she says something, he replies something. What is the exact dialogue? The third paragraph says "there ought to be a modern equivalent". Of what?

Comment: Are you asking whether the question *Wasn’t Chaplin in that one?* was idiomatic during the 1920s?

Comment: Reference to something is not "an expression".

Comment: @lambie although it looks like it was not "an expression" or a cliche etc but literally the fact that Chaplin made a movie with a plot that sounded similar to what Nucky had said, I was simply wondering, as explained abundantly, whether Billy had a made quip that people tended to make in similar context. does that not make sense?

Comment: This would probably be a better question if you asked why she said the line.

Comment: @Laurel: I think the question is extremely clear especially with my edit. i am done with this question and it was answered to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a reference to "A Dog's Life" (1918) in which Chaplin (and his dog) steal food from a burger van: [Charlie Chaplin and his brother Sydney in a scene from A Dog's Life (1918)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnlyIIMrZuk).